# How to debug in client side of Vaadin components?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Can it be possible to debug client-side of component ? I debugged client-side of vaadin components with my IDE(*Eclipse*) but I never caught any of break points . I think when compilling widgetset of components, Vaadin generates javascript representation for my client-side of components and run from them (*not from java class as server-side Vaadin component*). Below is sample structure of my component. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug client side of Vaadin, you have two options: Development Mode and SuperDevMode:

- Development Mode is not working anymore on latest Chrome and Firefox versions because it uses internal APIs of those browsers, and those APIs are not available anymore. But if you have a browser that still supports it (IE for example) and the Development Mode plugin has been installed on it and you have a Development Mode server up and running on your project correctly, you can use your IDE to debug client-side code. Just add a breakpoint on a client-side class and use the application on the browser. The break point should catch when the line is executed.
- SuperDevMode is the new way to debug client-side code of Vaadin (and GWT). With SuperDevMode debugging happens on the browser by using JavaScript debugging and the Source Maps feature which is available at least on latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.